# Talkback in EditText reading the content twice

Tags: android, android-edittext, talkback

I created an EditText and I tested it to use it with talkback. The problem is that it is reading it 2 times the first one it select the whole EditText and in the second one it select only the hint. This is only happening when the hint is visible. If I set the text this doesn't happen anymore.

[image]

[image]

I don't need the second one but I am not sure how can I avoid this.

The edit text is a regular AppCompatEditText:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/formInput"
        style="@style/MBInputTextInput"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/match_constraint"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="?spacing_35"
        android:minHeight="?spacing_100"
        android:paddingStart="?spacing_50"
        android:paddingTop="?spacing_40"
        android:paddingEnd="?spacing_50"
        android:paddingBottom="?spacing_40"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iconEnd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: you should paste your code too.

Comment: I pasted the code of the EditText that I am using... what else do you need to know?

Comment: java or kotlin code

Comment: @EliasFazel it is in kotlin but this really have something to do with talkback?

Comment: How is the text being set? Are you also setting the hint, or an error message? Is there any focus switching when opening the screen?

Comment: @PimTegelaar This is happening only with the hint, if a text is set it works fine. When you open the screen you start with the talkback going to next element and instead of going to the next one it focuses again in the same EditText and select only the hint. But I want to avoid this because it already says the hint when the focus is in the EditText